# How to use an non-custom frequency in pd.bdate_range with holiday parameters in pandas module?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to output a range of dates using pandas module with a frequency offset of MS and a holiday parameter, but it's failing since it's only allowed to use custom frequency when using the holidays parameter:

```
pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS', holidays=holiday_dates)
```

I tried using CustomBusinessDay, below is my implementation:

```
rng = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS') 
dates_list = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, freq=CDay(calendar=rng, holidays=holiday_dates))
```

But it seems like it does not inherit the frequency from the calendar=rng and is still defaulting to the daily one.

Can you point out what am I doing wrong? Thanks. Apologies if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: what's in holiday_dates?

Comment: just a list of dates with datetime format:  ['2014-08-01', '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01', '2014-12-01', '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01']

Comment: ok, sometimes holidays from libraries are empty, just checking